# Dynamically change header and template depending on the result in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am looking for a way to changed the template html headers and template dynamically.  So for example I have data that returns different columns fields and the number of columns and I need the headers to change accordingly. Sometimes I can get 4 columns returning and sometimes 10 columns. I am not sure if using a single view model is the correct way. Or what is the best way to approach this.

**HTML**

```
    <div id="GridSearch">

    <form>
        <input id="searchchild" type="text">
        <button type="submit" data-bind="click:PartnerSearchChildDetails">
        </button>
    </form>
    <div>Partner</div>
    <div>
        <select id="Partner" data-bind="options: Partners, optionsText: 'Partner', optionsValue: 'ID', value: selectedPartner, optionsCaption: 'Select'">
         </select>
     </div>

   <!-- This should change based on the result or option selected -->
     <div style="display: none" data-bind="visible:SearchResults().length>0">
        <div>Child ID</div>
        <div>Child Name</div>
    </div>

    <div id="PartnerSearchData" data-bind="template: { name:'TmplPartnerSearchResults', foreach: PartnerSearchResults }"></div>

    </div>
```

**Template**

Here I am trying to use an if condition which works but not sure how to get the HTML header part to change

```
  <script type="text/html" id="TmplPartnerSearchResults">  
       <!-- ko if: (objPartnerSearchDetails.ShowListing()==true) -->
              <div>
                   <div data-bind="text: ClientID"></div>
                   <div data-bind="text: ClientName">/div>
              </div>



      <!-- ko if: (objPartnerSearchDetails.ShowPLListing()==true) -->
              <div>
                   <div data-bind="text: PartnerID"></div>
                   <div data-bind="text: PartnerName">/div>
                   <div data-bind="text: PartnerMobile">/div>
               </div>
    </script>
```

Comment: Missing a `<!-- /ko -->` in those conditions? ([Virtual elements](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html) have an open and close tag)

Comment: Quick hack, but works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/oymdktwu/

Comment: @BradChristie I missed the ending tag but it there in my code.

Comment: Your fiddle works but not sure if the way I do it with the html part in one place and the script in another both in the same file though.  Will give it a try and let you know